# Need help on this error: ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python

```
from  xlrd import open_workbook
book = open_workbook('Workbook2.csv')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
keys = [sheet.cell(0,col_index).value for col_index in xrange(sheet.ncols)]
dict_list =[]

for row_index in xrange(1,sheet.nrows):
   d={keys[col_index]: sheet.cell(row_index, col_index).value for col_index in    xrange(sheet.ncols)}
   dict_list.append(d)

print dict_list

for i in range(len(dict_list)):
  for key,val in dict_list[i]:
    print val
```

Trying to print out the val, but it gives this error: ValueError: too many values to unpack. Anyone that can help?

Comment: `for key,val in dict_list[i].items()`?

Comment: What's the contents of the CSV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, if you're using Python 2:

```
for key, val in dict_list[i].iteritems():
```

Or with Python 3:

```
for key, val in dict_list[i].items():
```

Alternatively, if you want just the keys, or just the values, you can use `dict_list[i].keys()` and `dict_list[i].values()` respectively.

Comment: When you iterate through a dictionary, you only get the keys. It's not possible to unpack the key into the key/value pair. The value information is not even there. The `items()` method on a dictionary returns a list with key/value pairs, so if you got the dictionary `{'a': 1, 'b': 2}` it returns `[('a', 1), ('b', 2)]`. Now you can unpack this data into a key and a value. The `iteritems()` method doesn't return a list with the keys and values, but returns an iterator instead. This is usually the better option because the key/value list could take up a lot of memory.

Comment: In Python 3, the iteritems() method was removed and the items() method now returns an iterator there.

Comment: ok, this is what I got when I  print out val: [xxx, 123, www.123.com] [xxx, 245, www.245.com], You see two loops has happened. There is the question, how can I use each element, like how I can unpack xxx, or 123 from the val?

Comment: If it's an ordinary list, write `val[0]` to get the first entry, `val[1]` to get the second entry, and `val[2]` to get the third entry in the list.